# How do I keep a database of repo stats and user stats, in sync with github?

Tags: database, api, github, cron

How do I keep a database of repo stats and user stats, in sync with github?

I know that I can use

`curl https://api.github.com/repos/reggi/handwritten`

and

`curl https://api.github.com/users/reggi`

To get repo and user data.

But what's the best way to keep that in sync with my database?

I don't believe theres a webhook for this general data, like when a stargazer gets added.

Should I just have a cron script that updates the database daily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't believe theres a webhook for this general data, like when a stargazer gets added.

There is one event related to stargazing, and strangely enough, it is the [Watch Event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#watchevent).
See "[Upcoming Changes to Watcher and Star APIs](https://developer.github.com/changes/2012-9-5-watcher-api/)".

More generally, using **[WebHook](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/)** is a good way to be kept in sync with a lot of events regarding a repo or a user account.